# Finding lower bound for $\alpha(G) + \omega(G)$

Tags: graph-theory, upper-lower-bounds

I'm wondering to find a lower bound for $\alpha(G) + \omega(G)$.
In my tries, I couldn't find a graph without inequation: $\alpha(g).\omega(G) \geq |V(G)|$
Thus I think one possible bound is $\alpha(G) + \omega(G) \geq 2\sqrt n$, but I have no proof for this bound.